# I can't change the data_type from TINYTEXT to DATE&/DATETIME

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime, datetime-format

I'm using SQL 8.0 and still learning , and I did some good changes on it. Now i'm stuck by the date, they are in the `data_type` of `TINYTEXT` from the import and each of the other field are `VARCHAR(60)` or `INT` for the Primary Key and I did pretty good job on it but i'm stuck for the `data_type` of the date.

I did this since the first day: it worked for `date` type

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(column_name , "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s")
FROM table_name;
```

(For a Datetime
 It didn't work.)

now I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO database_test.table_test.field_name(today) 
VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('07-25-2012','%m-%d-%y') )
```

Instead of `%m-%d%y`, I need this European format: `%d/%m/%Y` for DATE.
And `%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s` for my `DATETIME`. Both are in `TINYTEXT`.
(NB:they are date from 1899 to 2099 for the future "DATE" data_type.)

Comment: The ANSI SQL standard date format (as used by MySQL) is `Y-m-d` - if you convert your date strings to that format you *should* then be able to convert the field type from `TINYTEXT` to `DATE` - then you can use native date manipulation functions like `DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: Should I use SELECT... FROM to do this or it's preferable to do ALTER TABLE for using DATE_format?

Comment: Once you've converted the existing text to a valid date format, you'll want to `ALTER TABLE` yes - I think that'll work but **back up the table first**, if something goes wonky you could end up losing all the dates when you alter the table.

Comment: I'm working on an alernate table for test. I'm not changing my work. I'm gonna try this lines.-

Comment: I did try to change the format date, so I tried to search the command on Internet. I found the getdate() function, and even this it doesn't work.-

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a couple of assumptions...

1. by *SQL 8.0* you mean **MySQL 8.0** (`STR_TO_DATE` is non-standard so may not work with other database servers)
2. dates in your `TINYTEXT` field are stored in the format `%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s`

... and for the sake of argument I'm going to say the `TINYTEXT` date field is called `date_string`.

What I'd do is create a new `DATE` column and then `UPDATE` it with the value from `date_string` - using the `STR_TO_DATE` function (like you tried) - and if that's successful remove the original column and, possibly, rename the new `DATE` column.

---

**Add the *real date* column**

I'm calling it `date_date` here.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_test` ADD `date_date` DATE NOT NULL AFTER `date_string`;
```

**UPDATE the *real date* with the value from the TINYTEXT field**

(assuming `d/m/Y H:i:s` format)

```
UPDATE `table_test` SET `date_date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date_string`, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

That *should* work as long as the format in your `TINYTEXT` column matches the format set in the `STR_TO_DATE` function. You'll have the original and converted dates in the table for now anyway, so you can check that the data looks OK.

Comment: It works well for the 'UPDATE `clien` SET `date_date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date_string`, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');' It gave me a Warning, but the rows changed. And I tried to put the real data from the test table in the new field. I tried this next lines:

Comment: `SELECT date_string update date_date from table;` or even 
`With date_date as date_primary INSERT INTO date_string VALUES( __/__/___, __/__/___, etc... )` Instead of __/__/____ it's real data, and I put it as a list like the term `IN`.- I didn't find the good request to put all my test rows into the new field date_date. Sorry for that easy way that I miss. I'm still learning.

Comment: @BenoîtCode Sorry - I'm struggling a little with your English... are you saying that you had some dates that were incorrectly formatted in your `TINYTEXT` field which you've now corrected and it's working ...? Do you need any further help or are you OK now?